# regular expression need to work for both type of strings

Tags: regex

I have two strings like this:

1. `PDY_24.45_USD_ASTRO`
2. `PDY_24.45USD_ASTRO`

I need to replace `24.45_USD` and `24.45USD` with `*`

What I have written is

```
final String REPLACEDIGITS= "(\\d*\\.\\d*)(\\_)(\\w{3})";
```

But its working for one and not for the other. If I remove `\\_` it works for other. But I want a regex which will be working for both. Any solution for ignoring `_`

Thanks,
swapna

Comment: Google would have helped here: http://www.google.com/search?q=regex+optional+match (first result)

Answer (score 1):

To make something optional you add a `?` afterwards, so you would use `_?` to optionally match an underscore

This expression:

```
(\d+(\.\d+)?)_?(\w{3})
```

Will make the underscore optional, and will also allow whole numbers i.e. `25_USD` or `25USD` as well as `24.45_USD` and `24.45USD`

Answer (score 0):

Try `(\d*\.\d*)(\_)?(\w{3})` instead.